# "Managing" AlarmManager. How to detect if I already have Repeating alarm running?

Tags: android

I have service that I need to run every 5 minutes. I already have code to schedule repeating Alarm on device boot. It works but

1. When installing app and running it my alarm doesn't run. Need to reboot debice. This is expected.
2. If I start repeating alarm on activity start then I'm not sure if I already have alarm going from device boot. Will I get "doubles"? Will it run 2 alarms?

Basically, I want to make sure that I start alarm if user reboots device or battery dies, etc. But I also don't wan't them to reboot device when app installed to get it started. Or, for example if user "Force close" and then run app - it won't run this service anymore but it needs to. And, I don't want double-runs. I just need once every 5 minutes.

How this can/need to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When installing app and running it my alarm doesn't run. Need to reboot debice. This is expected.

You do not have to wait until a reboot. Schedule your initial alarms on the first run of your app.

> If I start repeating alarm on activity start then I'm not sure if I already have alarm going from device boot. Will I get "doubles"? Will it run 2 alarms?

So long as it is an equivalent `PendingIntent`, it should replace the existing alarm, AFAIK.

Comment: I will make it equivalent. So, I can just start it on main activity start and that will do? Doesn't matter how many times activity start? But timer itself will be "broken". If I start to run after 1 and every 5 then if user start app at 2:00 - service will start at 2:01. Next time user start app at 2:02 - service will start at 2:03. This is not crucial detail, but do I understand correctly?

Comment: @katit: I am sorry but I do not understand your comment. You are the one scheduling the alarm. You are the one who controls when the alarm goes off. You, therefore, are the one that needs to do whatever calculations are necessary to accomplish that end. Again, if you establish your alarms on the first run of your app after installation, and then again on a reboot, you should be in OK shape.

Comment: How do I know when "first run after install" happen? Best I can do is go by Application.onCreate. And also I can put something in preferences which I don't like to do ideally.

I guess I'm not sure how lifecycle works. If I hit HOME and stop my app - Alarms will still work every 5 (but I don't know WHEN because they just repeat after 5). User starts app and I schedule another Alarm that will replace existing but again, I don't know when next execution needed to be. I guess I can schedule to run on 5's like 00:05, 00:10 and so on..

Comment: @katit: "How do I know when "first run after install" happen?" -- check your `SharedPreferences` for a `isFirstRun` `boolean` value. If it has not been set, it is your first run, so set up your alarm and stuff `true` in the `SharedPreferences`. Or use your own file if you prefer. "Best I can do is go by Application.onCreate" -- you misunderstand. I mean you set up the alarm for the first run of your app EVER ON THE DEVICE.

Comment: I don't think so. If user goes to applications and says "Force Stop" - alarm will be killed. And if user starts app afterwards alarm won't be started if I use flag like that. But it will be started on device reboot. But that's not big deal. I can start it every time on Application start since you said it is replacing previous one (if it exist)

Answer (score -1):

If you or someone else is still having trouble with this, I can share what I ended up using to solve the problem.

First, let me restate the problem as I understand it, since there seems to have been some confusion: you would like to do something (in your case, set an alarm) once, when the application is first booted. Not when one of the application's activity is brought to the forefront. And not *just* once ever.

The first activity you load at boot has an onCreate method with a parameter that will help you greatly:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
```

The first time this activity runs, savedInstanceState will equal null. Every time thereafter it will not be null. Use this to trigger whether or not to *do something* upon application boot. This is how I determine whether or not to start a service at boot.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. If the user exits your application (with back button from the only activity in the task) and then reenters, the savedInstanceState will be null, even though the process might not be restarted and alarms were not removed.